# How to Manage Guest Users with Php and SQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using PHP , MySQL for Handling My site. I have a user table called **user_table** containing **user_id PRIMARY** and Now user can chat with other user. For that I am using a table called **message_table**. this table contains essential fields like msg_id , sender_id , reciver_id , replay_id etc. this works very fine.But I need to handle also guest users[Not registered] with this chat. how can I handle them. I inserted the guset_id as the mixture of **entering time** and **his name** to a table called guest_table. Now I can use this guest_table like user_table. Is that a good idea ?

Answer (score 2):

> But I need to handle also guest users[Not registered] with this chat.

These guests look to me like a special sort of user.  I suggest you handle them as if they were users. You may wish to put a column called something like `is_guest` in your user table, and set it to `1` when you know the user is a guest.

**Keeping a separate table, parallel to the user table, for your guests is NOT a good idea.** It will greatly complicate your queries, especially when a person in your user table communicates with a person in your guest table.

Instead, put everybody in the user table, guests and registered users alike.

A nice little benefit: if you convert a guest to a registered user, all you have to do is flip the is_guest flag and let them specify their own username and other data. They get to keep their history.